# What is the purpose of an sqs in a stepfunction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless, aws-step-functions

So I'm trying to wrap my head around what the purpose of having an sqs in a stepfunction is.

Lets say there's a lambda that sends messages to an queue, and then another lambda that consumes the messages when they're ready, all wrapped in a stepfunction. What is the use case for this? Is this bad stepfunction design?

If the first lambda has a lot of messages to send to the queue, then it's likely that the queue will have processed the messages and the third lambda will have already started consuming the messages (assuming the third lambda has been configured to listen for messages that are ready from the queue). If this were the case, then three different states would be active all at one time.

Since there's a limit of 256kb transfer between states, a use case like this can't be too uncommon right?

Then when the third lambda is done processing the messages, then assuming it's not the end of the stepfunction, there are more states to be run. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: My first guess would be for idempotency and/or DLQ/replay capabilities, but it's hard to say what the purpose might be without looking at the actual implementation in detail.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% follow what you are looking to do here, but it seems you may be describing a conflation of approaches. Typically, when you use Step Functions to orchestrate Lambda Function invocations, you would not have the Lambda Function also send messages to an SQS that triggered the same Lambda Functions. You either orchestrate your Lambda Function invocations using a Step Functions workflow. Or you choreograph Lambda Function invocations by triggering from SQS queues and then writing results to queues in your Function code or, preferrably, using Lambda Destinations.

Comment: One pattern you will see is to have Step Functions send a message to an SQS queue using .waitForCallback and trigger a Lambda Function from that queue, which then responds back to Step Functions using SendTask* API Actions. This can be helpful when you want to control concurrency of Lambda Function invocations orchestrated by your state machines.

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit I can see from the use case you described is:

- The ability to mutate the input & output between activities (i.e. strip away the SQS metadata and only pass in the body of the message to the final Lambda)
- A more convenient way to debug issues, as you can trace all of the data passed into each state within a Step Functions execution.

You wouldn't want to have triggers setup between the components (SQS + Lambda) and also have those wrapped in a Step Functions workflow.